# Filtering element based on existence of child node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I wanted to filter elements based on the existence of their child nodes, how would I do that in `d3.js`?

For example in this html structure, how would I select the `<li>` elements that have children `<a>` elements?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>Bullet</li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li>Bullet</li>
</ul>
```

For those who don't know, [it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own questions...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Why did you ask this question if you knew the answer?

Comment: @Recursed: Why wouldn't he? StackOverflow allows this as long as it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @amnotiam yeah. there should be a time limit, of say 30 minutes, before someone can ***attempt*** to answer their own question ...

Comment: @Xander: If you click the *Ask Question* button, you'll see that StackOverflow actually has a feature that lets you post a Question and Answer at the same time.

Comment: Wow, I'm a little disappointed, having been quite misled from this article: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: If down-voters are down-voting because they don't like the self Q/A style, then they're down-voting for the wrong reason. You should be rating the quality of the question and answer. Read the FAQ and you'll see that this is explicitly ***permitted***.

Comment: @amnotiam you don't think I would downvote this if someone asked this genuinely? :D There is no research effort and no code attempts. It's also possible to make these kinds of questions infinitely and answer them ("I have this html , how to select those elements")

Comment: @Esailija: Hmm... can't tell if you're joking, but assuming the desired solution is D3 specific, and considering the solution has been posted, I think this qualifies. *(I have no idea if it's a good D3 solution, or not.)*

Comment: @amnotiam I am not joking, if this was a genuine question, people would downvote because there is no research effort and no code. As a self answered post it sucks because it's just a very localized "here's this html, how to select these elements like that".

Comment: @Esailija: Actually I think it's very general, and a specific HTML structure has been given for illustration. WRT research effort/code attempts, that criteria doesn't seem necessary when it is posted as an answer. This Q/A will benefit a D3 user who needs to solve the problem. *(Again, notwithstanding the code quality question.)*

Comment: @amnotiam ok I have edited the question to make that more clear but the reality is that *instantly* self answered posts are not usually well received

Comment: @Esailija - I'm confused, because in the article it says that "**it is explicitly encouraged**"

Comment: I don't care what the article says, I mean whenever I have seen instantly self answered questions they have been received negatively. Might have been the quality of those questions/answers but still.

Comment: @Esailija: I think that was a good edit. The more generalized part was in the title. This makes it more clear. For self Q/A, it's probably a good idea to make sure that the question quality and clarity are high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`filter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) function:

```
var ul = d3.select("ul");
var lis = ul.selectAll("li").filter(function() {
    return ! d3.select(this).select("a").empty();
});
```

Comment: You could rewrite the filter as `return !d3.select(this).select("a").empty()`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that I had overlooked something.

Comment: The beauty of this way, as opposed to the other answer, is that it also makes it possible to select elements that _don't_ contain a particular child: just remove the exclamation mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cold solve the problem using native Javascript:

First you can select all "a" elements inside a "li" element:

```
var childLinks = document.querySelectorall("ul li a");   // Supported By IE8+
```

Then you can select, for each of them, the parent:

```
childLinks[0].parentNode
```

Native methods should be faster.